# Detect word palindrome in a paragraph using C#

Tags: c#, palindrome

i want to make a program is intended to count the number of palindrome words in the paragraph and the number of its occurrences

Rules and assumptions:

1. Input: User can enter a paragraph containing as many sentences as possible. Each word 
   is separated by a whitespace, and each sentence is separated by a period.
2. Output: The list of palindrome words found in the input, and the number of its 
   occurrences.
3. The punctuation right before or after the word willbe ignored, while the punctuation 
   inside the word will be counted. The palindrome also ignores the letter case. 
   a.  I have a Honda Civic.  Civicis palindrome, the punctuation after the word is 
   ignored. 
   b.  My li’l brother is sleeping. li’l is not a palindrome, because there is a 
   punctuation inside the word.

Sample Input:

Otto wants to have a dog. He walks up the street and is about to step into the pets 
store when he sees a sign that reads ‘Step on no pets’ hanging on the door. Otto 
sees a lot of animals at the pets store. He sees the birds. He sees the squirrels. He 
sees the chameleons. He sees the dogs. “How much does the dog cost?” Otto says. 
“Ten dollars,” the man says. Otto gives the man tendollars. Otto buys the dog. The 
dog walks home with Otto. Now Otto has a dog. “Thank God now I have a dog,” he 
says to himself.

Sample Output: 
Otto = 7 A = 5 Sees = 6

my codes is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PalindromeProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a String"); 
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            string words = s.ToLower();
            string[] hasil = words.Split(' ');
            foreach (string temp in hasil)
            {
                string str = string.Empty;
                int x = temp.Length;

                for (int y = x - 1; y >= 0; y--)
                {
                    str = str + temp[y];
                }

                int count = 0;
                if (str == temp)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine(temp + " is palindrome = " + count);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output result of my code, whene i put paragrapht :

Otto wants to have a dog. He walks up the street and is about to step into the pets store when he sees a sign that reads ‘Step on no pets’ hanging on the door. Otto sees a lot of animals at the pets store. He sees the birds. He sees the squirrels. He sees the chameleons. He sees the dogs. “How much does the dog cost?” Otto says. “Ten dollars,” the man says. Otto gives the man tendollars. Otto buys the dog. The dog walks home with Otto. Now Otto has a dog. “Thank God now I have a dog,” he says to himself.

my outputs program is :

otto is palindrome = 1 a is palindrome = 1 otto is palindrome = 1 sees is palindrome = 1

i want my output program like this:

word Otto = 7, word A = 5,  word Sees = 6

please fix my output result...

Comment: show your code.  we can't help you unless you show us what you've already done.

Comment: you need to store a unique count for each palindrome found. after you are done iterating through the paragraph, print out your findings

Comment: Could you add some comments to your code? It's hard for me to understand the algorithm. Also, is the code getting compiled, or is it giving wrong output?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag appropriately.

Comment: your imperative style does not correspond to your nick :)

Comment: @BrunoBrant, `homework` tag is obsolete : http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: @psycho, really? OMG, I'm getting old. LOL. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that you process the text via pipeline with following steps:

1. split text to words
2. find palindromes
3. group same words into buckets
4. map buckets to projection with word and it's count in bucket
5. extract projections to the list
6. and then out that list to console

.

```
var s = @"<<< your input string here >>>";

var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+").Cast<Match>() //1
        .Select(m => m.Value.ToLower()) //1
        .Where(w => String.Join("", w.Reverse()) == w) //2
        .GroupBy(w => w) //3
        .Select(g => new {Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}) //4
        .ToList(); //5

result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); //6
```

Outputs:

```
{ Word = otto, Count = 7 }
{ Word = a, Count = 5 }
{ Word = sees, Count = 6 }
```

Not sure if it will cover punctuation -- need to tweak reqular expression. Will let it for you. :) I guess the only case is apostrophe in words like `I'll`. That case may be handled by changing regexp pattern to `\w|'+` (that means any letter or apostrophe, occurring one or more time).

Comment: I think you should give some explanations on what does your code do...

Comment: it finds palindromes and counts them

Comment: Not all palindromes have been found, for instance, "I".

Comment: He doesn't mean "what does it do", he means "how does it do it". Your answer, while accurate in answering the question, doesn't help anyone but this particular user for this particular problem. What happens when he has another problem similar to this (but different enough) and tries using this technique and fails? You've done nothing to "help" him as he'll come back asking for more help, which defeats the purpose of SO.

Comment: @BrunoBrant that was done by intent (I removed palindromes that are present only once). But finally I removed that line from question. thx

Comment: Just extended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of way to do this. Out of the top of my mind, try splitting the paragraph into words, removing duplicates and for each resulting word, and then check if its a palindrome.

There are, of course, many ways to optimize this algorithm.

---

Looking at your code, the only error -- and probably the *most complex issue* in this problem -- is correctly splitting the paragraph. You used string.Split(' '), which means that only sequence of characters separated by spaces are turned into "words" (items in your array). However, the resulting array may contain an item with

> dog,”

which is clearly not a word.

---

There are many ways to achieve the correct split. the_joric answer used Regex, which, while powerful, is too complex and hard to understand, which may lead into errors.

(I'm not saying I wouldn't use it for this particular problem; I'm just saying that maybe it's too big of a leap to a C# newcomer).

So I'll try writing the solution in some other way:

Let's define what is a *word* for our particular **problem domain**, shall we? For me, a *word* is a sequence of one or more characters that use only letters. So, "guess", "what" and "asd" is a word. However, "123asd" or "a1s2d3" or "asd123" aren't.

On the other hand, maybe "asd." is a word following a period. So, let's follow a **heuristic** approach in that anything other than a letter will be a "separator". So, "123asd" will yield "asd" as a word, and "a1s2d3" will yield "a", "b" and "c".

```
const string validChars = "abcdefghijklmenopqrstuvwxyz";

List<string> GetAllWords(string inputSentence)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    string word = string.Empty;
    foreach (var c in inputSentence.ToLower())
    {
        if (validChars.IndexOf(c) >= 0)
        {
            word += c;
        }
        else if (word != string.Empty)
        {
            list.Add(word);
            word = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

The method above will return a list of words following our heuristic. It is not perfect, as I have already stated, but considering a **well formed text**, it will work. Replace your "string.Split(...)" with this algorithm and you are good to go.